# Async Get in ASP.net Web API does not close the connection when there is a GetResponseAsync in it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

Here is my code :

```cs
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
    {

        var url = "some url here";
        string content;
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
  /*1*/ using (HttpWebResponse webresponse = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
  /*2*/         content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
        }
        var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");

        return response;
    }
```

and my problem:

When I try to visit this get in my IE, the connect is marked as pending all the time and nothing is shown. And in FireFox, I can read part of the data, and it is likely missing the last a few characters with the tab showing a spinning icon.

I guess it is because the HTTP connection is not closed by my IIS express( and with a few characters not flushed).

I tried to modify my code in line 1 and 2. The result is if I change line 1 into a synchronous call `request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse`, everything works fine as I expect, no mater what is in line 2, the `ReadtoEnd()`, async or sync .

I can use a workaround that only call `request.GetResponse()` to make everything works, but I want to know why this happens.

Comment: do you block on the task further up the call stack with wait() or result()?